# java.lang.RuntimeException trying to use recycled bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I have this error when I run this code. It says `java.lang.RuntimeException trying to use recycled bitmap`. They say I should use `Bitmap.recycle()` but I'm having this error. Is my code correct?

Here is my code:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
bMap.recycle();
```

Comment: [Have a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/477572/940096)

Comment: Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+runtimeexception+trying+to+use+a+recycled+bitmap) before asking. [See also](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+runtimeexception+canvas+trying+to+use+a+recycled+bitmap).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this code:

```
if (null != bMap && !bMap .getBitmap().isRecycled()) 
{
    bMap .getBitmap().recycle();
} else {
    log("bitmap is already recycled");
}
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: where should i put this? from the bottom after the image.setBitmap?

Comment: It has an error in getBitmap. It says "It has an error for type bitmap"